# Extending Matplotlib Ray with 2 Coordinates to edge of Chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I have a chart with a main plot (in blue) that represents a value and support/resistance plots in red and green.  I want to extend the support lines to the edge of the chart rather than having the line stop at the second coordinate provided to each line. In the image you can see where I chose two of the support / resistance lines and marked 'x' where the coordinates are for those lines.  How do I have the line continue to the right until it reaches the edge of the chart?

```
import numpy as np
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,8), dpi=80)
ax = plt.axes()
ax.plot(df['Close'][2300:])

for i, d in enumerate(phase_width_indices_opp):
  t, h = d
  x, y = [t, h], [df['High'][t], df['High'][h]]
  plt.plot(x, y, alpha=0.1, color='red', linewidth=1)

for i, d in enumerate(phase_width_indices_opp):
  t, h = d
  x, y = [t, h], [df['Low'][t], df['Low'][h]]
  plt.plot(x, y, alpha=0.1, color='green', linewidth=1)
```

[image]

To be a little more concise with my question ... the essence of what I am asking is this: when you draw a line in matplotlib with a given `x1, y1, x2, y2` how do you have the line continue to the edge of the chart on the right side of the line?  The data that I'm plotting is irrelevant here, I just need help extending a line in matplotlib without knowing where it'll intersect with the edge of the chart.